Remove unexpected space added to the first line in a verse in a itemize list
I am trying to typeset poetry in a list (itemize). For this purpose I utilize the native itemize and verse environments. For my specific usage the left margin of the verse content shall be the same as it is for normal text in the list, except for when a line has to be broken. In this latter case, the indentation shall be as default with the verse environment.
To achieve this I changed the following lengths in the verse environment
\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt} % This aligns the left margin of poem typeset in verse environment only, see bottom example
    \setlength{\leftmarginii}{0pt} % This aligns the left margin of poem typeset in verse environment as an item in itemize, see below example
    }

This ensures that the left margin is as described above both for verse environments inside a list, and outside in the text - except for the first line in the verse placed in itemize list. See picture below, where this unwanted (and unexpected) space is marked in red.
Is there a way to remove this specific space so that the first line is flush with the left margin of the other items?
Example output showing unwanted space

MWE of above output
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrarticle}
%\usepackage{verse}
\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt} % This aligns the left margin of poem typeset in verse environment only, see bottom example
    \setlength{\leftmarginii}{0pt} % This aligns the left margin of poem typeset in verse environment as an item in itemize, see below example
    }
\begin{document}
 This is normal text, written only to show how it behaves.
    \begin{itemize}
        
    \item \begin{verse}
This is a poem\\ 
        typeset in the \texttt{verse} environment, which is suited for this\\
        end of that
    \end{verse}
    \item Normal text
    \end{itemize}
    
    \begin{verse}
     This poem is\\ 
     typeset in \texttt{verse} environment outside of any other environment\\
     end of that
    \end{verse}
    
    Some other normal text. It is long enough that there are at least two lines.
\end{document}


Place a % (comment) character at the end of the \AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{ line.

Thank you for pointing that out @Mico. I added it now to the MWE, but it was not the cause for the additional space.

I don't know if the koma classes modify verse. if not, consider using the verse package as it is a bit more flexible than the latex default environment and it is easier to keep things consistent. (but if you are typesetting a poem or a collection of poems, you should maybe use a class designed for that rather than any package.)

By changing \leftmarginii you also change \labelsep and you must compensate that:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{%
 \setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
 \setlength{\labelsep}{-\leftmarginii}
 \setlength{\leftmarginii}{0em}
 }
 

\begin{document}
 This is normal text, written only to show how it behaves.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \begin{verse}
This is a poem\\ 
        typeset in the \texttt{verse} environment, which is suited for this\\
        end of that
    \end{verse} 
    \item Normal text
    \end{itemize}
    
    \begin{verse}
     This poem is\\ 
     typeset in \texttt{verse} environment outside of any other environment\\
     end of that
    \end{verse}
    
    Some other normal text. It is long enough that there are at least two lines.
\end{document}



You are explicitly adding space after setting the length. Don't leave a space between a curly bracket and a comment or new line.
\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}% This aligns the left margin of poem typeset in verse environment only, see bottom example
    \setlength{\leftmarginii}{0pt}% This aligns the left margin of poem typeset in verse environment as an item in itemize, see below example
    }


Thank you for pointing this out @cfr. However, the spaces between the right parentheses and the percent was not the cause for the additional space in the output.
